# how check existence of specified add-in in visio using vba

Tags: vba, visio

I am trying to find a way to check existence of Add-In in Microsoft Visio using VBA. When I using Excel I can use object “Addin” in object model “Excel”. So if in Excel I can use next function, for example.

```
Function ExistsAddin(NameAddin As String) As Boolean
Dim objAddin As AddIn   
Dim i As Long           
        For i = 1 To Application.AddIns.count
            Set objAddin = Application.AddIns.item(i)
            If objAddin.name = NameAddin Then
                ExistsAddin = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        ExistsAddin = False
End Function
```

But object model Visio haven’t object “AddIn”.  Can anyone help me out with my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for a [Visio COMAddin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765398.aspx) instead.

```
Function ExistsAddin(NameAddin As String) As Boolean
Dim objAddin As Visio.COMAddIn
Dim i As Long           
        For i = 1 To Visio.COMAddIns.count
            Set objAddin = Visio.COMAddIns.item(i)
            If objAddin .name = NameAddin Then
                ExistsAddin = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        ExistsAddin = False
End Function
```

Please note the above code is not tested as I do not have visio.

Comment: Unfortunately, I must check existence of COM Add-In in Visio, not Addon

Comment: COMAddin then, it seems. I updated the link and the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me!